# need to append user data to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, push

my original question got answered but I realize that every time I try to push user data in the arrays it wouldn't allow me to do is there any another to append data to arrays or is the push method the only way. or should i create a new array................................................................

```js
"use strict"

const names = ["Ben", "Joel", "Judy", "Anne"];
const scores = [88, 98, 77, 88];


const $ = selector => document.querySelector(selector);

const addScore = () => {
  //  get user entries
  const name = $("#name").value;
  const score = parseInt($("#score").value);
  let isValid = true;

  // check entries for validity
  if (name == "") {
    $("#name").nextElementSibling.textContent = "This field is required.";
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    $("#name").nextElementSibling.textContent = "";
  }

  if (isNaN(score) || score < 0 || score > 100) {
    $("#score").nextElementSibling.textContent = "You must enter a valid score.";
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    $("#score").nextElementSibling.textContent = "";
  }

  if (isValid) {
    names.push("#name");
    scores.push("#score");
    names[names.length] = name;
    scores[scores.length] = score;
    $("#name").value = "";
    $("#score").value = "";
  }

  $("#name").focus();



};

// display scores
const displayScores = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("scores_display").textContent += names[i] + " = " +
      scores[i] +
      "\n";
  }
};


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  $("#add").addEventListener("click", addScore);
  $("#display_scores").addEventListener("click", displayScores())
  $("#name").focus();
});
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Use a Test Score array</h1>

  <div>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <span></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="score">Score:</label>
    <input type="text" id="score">
    <span></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Add to Array">
    <input type="button" id="display_scores" value="Display Scores">
  </div>

  <div>
    <textarea id="scores_display"></textarea>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Explain *"it wouldn't allow me"* in more specific detail including errors thrown (if any)

Comment: I haven't gotten any errors but every time i try to use the push method to add the user data to the arrays nothing happen. This is my first time using jquery i thought it was my syntax but that doesn't seems to be the problem but i believe its the placement of the push methods I tried to put the methods  in a separate if statement but nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All my previous notes were incorrect. Your adhoc `$` const threw me off! My apologies.

The issue was you weren't calling displayScores() after updating the array. Plus, I added a line to that function to clear the existing text before looping through your data.

```js
"use strict"

const names = ["Ben", "Joel", "Judy", "Anne"];
const scores = [88, 98, 77, 88];


const $ = selector => document.querySelector(selector);

const addScore = () => {
  //  get user entries
  const name = $("#name").value;
  const score = parseInt($("#score").value);
  let isValid = true;

  // check entries for validity
  if (name == "") {
    $("#name").nextElementSibling.textContent = "This field is required.";
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    $("#name").nextElementSibling.textContent = "";
  }

  if (isNaN(score) || score < 0 || score > 100) {
    $("#score").nextElementSibling.textContent = "You must enter a valid score.";
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    $("#score").nextElementSibling.textContent = "";
  }

  if (isValid) {
    names.push("#name");
    scores.push("#score");
    names[names.length] = name;
    scores[scores.length] = score;
    $("#name").value = "";
    $("#score").value = "";
    // add to the textarea
    displayScores()
  }

  $("#name").focus();
};

// display scores
const displayScores = () => {
  document.getElementById("scores_display").textContent = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("scores_display").textContent += names[i] + " = " +
      scores[i] +
      "\n";
  }
};


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  $("#add").addEventListener("click", addScore);
  $("#display_scores").addEventListener("click", displayScores())
  $("#name").focus();
});
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Use a Test Score array</h1>

  <div>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <span></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="score">Score:</label>
    <input type="text" id="score">
    <span></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Add to Array">
    <input type="button" id="display_scores" value="Display Scores">
  </div>

  <div>
    <textarea rows="6" id="scores_display"></textarea>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: i tried it still isn't pushing to the array

Comment: I'm trying to implement you code but it still isnt working do you think its because DOMcontentLoaded at the botttom

Comment: I think it's good now. Check my revised answer. Cheers